# Geometry package: Center footer relating to the pagewidth

Tags: header-footer, margins, page-numbering, geometry

I'm working on the final layout of my text.
I've set some margins with the `geometry` package:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newpagecolor{cyan}
\geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=20mm, right=90mm, bottom=15mm,
nohead, nomarginpar,
footskip=10mm, includefoot, 
showframe
}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Now my problem is that the pagenumber in the footer appears horizontally centered relating to the textwidth, but I need it centered relating to the pagewidth:

[image]

Comment: Since this is a rather odd layout, what is the space on the right side of the page for exactly?

Comment: I increased the right margin to demonstrate the problem

Comment: My point was that a one-sided document usually has symmetrical horizontal margins unless allowance is being made for something specific e.g. margin notes or binding. In that case, `geometry` offers specific ways to accommodate the required changes and you'd be best using those. The size of the change required isn't the point.

Comment: A larger margin right is a requirement (for corrections), so yes, it's asymmetrical. I didn't find anything in the manual which helps me

Comment: Personally, I would centre the page number relative to the text block in that case.  But I assume the lopsidedness is another bizarre institutional requirement and you're stuck with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any package, you can redefine `\@oddfoot`; but I don't find it a good idea. You don't need to do any computation including the paper width, just take into account the margins and `\hfil` will do the rest.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{
  a4paper,
  top=25mm,
  left=20mm,
  right=90mm,
  bottom=15mm,
  nohead,
  nomarginpar,
  footskip=10mm,
  includefoot,
  heightrounded,
  showframe,
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand\@oddfoot{%
    \hspace*{\dimexpr\Gm@rmargin-\Gm@lmargin}% right margin minus left margin
    \hfil\thepage\hfil
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Normally, one-sided documents have equal left and right margins unless allowance is required to accommodate something specific e.g. marginal notes or a binding.

Assuming that neither is the case and you are just aiming for a lopsided look, you could use `fancyhdr` (or another similar package) to implement the offset. For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newpagecolor{cyan}
\geometry{%
  top=25mm,
  left=20mm,
  right=90mm,
  bottom=15mm,
  nohead,
  nomarginpar,
  footskip=10mm,
  includefoot,
  showframe}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}%
  \fancyheadoffset[lf]{-85mm}% set to .5\paperwidth - \leftmargin
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhf[lf]{\thepage}%
}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

I've no idea why your example has to use cyan coloured paper, but there you go:

[image: lopsided cyan monster]